# Could be arbitrary template parameters used in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a simple "pipes and filters"-type architecture in my application. I would have a common base class for all filters having one input and one output type parameters. I would register the next filter for all filters, so they form a simple chain. I have one small problem: how should I represent the next filter's output type as a type parameter (like the _ in prolog? - the input of the next object should match the current filter's output, but the current filter should not know the output type of the next filter).

```
class IFilter
{
    std::auto_ptr<TIn> params;
    IFilter *nextFilter;
public:
    typedef TIn TInType;
    typedef TOut TOutType;

    void SetParams(std::auto_ptr<TIn> param) {  ...irrelevant code... }
    virtual void Execute() = 0;
    void Register(IFilter<TOutType, ???> *filter) { ...irrelevant code... }
};
```

Comment: Do you want long chains?  If so, composing a filter with another changes its type, so the result must be another value.  Or rather, if you have a fioter `A->B` and a filter `B->C` then the result of them being composed is `A->C`.  If registration just hooks filter2s input to filter1s input, I guess a new value is not needed.  Next Q: do you need an abstract interface, or is a pattern good enough?  How about implicit conversion -- `double` to `int` -- do you not care, want to block it, or want it?

Answer (score 0):

Just create template function:

```
template <class In, class Out>
class Filter
{
public:
    template <class T>
    void Register(Filter<Out, T>*)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    Filter<int, float> f1;
    Filter<float, double> f2;
    f1.Register(&f2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a template function work?

```
template<typename TIn, typename TOut>
struct Filter {
    template<typename NextTOut>
    void reg(Filter<TOut, NextTOut> *filter) {};
};

template<typename TIn, typename TOut>
struct Filter2 : Filter<TIn,TOut> {
};

template<typename TIn, typename TOut>
struct Filter3 : Filter<TIn,TOut> {
};

int main()
{
    Filter2<int,bool> f2;
    Filter3<bool,char> f3;

    f2.reg(&f3);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you're saying is that

```
Filter<int, float> f1;
Filter<float, double> f2;
```

can be composed as `f1->f2` but not `f2->f1`. That's fairly trivial. This is how it's done:

```
template<typename Tin, Tout>
class IFilter {
  // ...
  template<typename U>
  std::auto_ptr<IFilter<Tin, U> >
  operator->(std::auto_ptr<IFilter<Tout, U> > second) const
  {
    return std::auto_ptr<IFilter<Tin, U> >(
       new CompositeFilter(this, second));
  }
};
```

The compiler will complain if it the output type of the first filer (`Tout`) is not the input type of the second filter. In that case there's no matching `operator->`.